# Differentiation question - (an application of similarity solutions)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I've got this question which requires me to do some differentiation.

I define some stuff below:

$$\psi = x^{\frac{1}{3}} f(\eta)$$
where, $$\eta = \frac{y}{x^\frac{2}{3}}$$

I need to find the following derivatives:

[image]

Of course I need to do these individually and if someone could help me walkthrough how to do the derivatives.

1. Firstly, i've found out $$\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$Then, $$\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} = \ \  \frac{-2}{3} x^{-5/3}y = \ \  \frac{-2\eta}{3x} $$
2. Next, I need to find the individual derivatives and I've worked out how to do : $$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} = x^{1/3} \frac{df}{dn} \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y} =   \ \ x^{1/3} \cdot \frac{y}{x^{2/3}} \frac{df}{d\eta} = \frac{y}{x^{1/3}} \frac{df}{d\eta}$$
3. **I'm quite confused on how to do higher derivatives like** $$\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y^2} $$ So if you could help me on this please
4. **Also, I'm really confused on how to compute** $$\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x \partial y} $$

If you could help me figure these derivatives out it would be really helpful - thank you!

Edit: Changed title

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles. Also, please ask one question at a time.

Comment: I will change the question thank you @Shaun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative with respect to y should be (as you calculated correct):
$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}=x^{-1/3}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\eta}$$
Then we get:
$$\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y^2}=x^{-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2f}{\mathrm{d}\eta^2}$$
If we want to determine $\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x\partial y} $ we have to use the product rule, which should give:
$$\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x\partial y}  =\frac{\partial x^{-1/3}}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\eta}+ x^{-1/3}\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\eta}=-\frac{2y \frac{\mathrm{d^2}f}{\mathrm{d}\eta^2}+x^{2/3} \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\eta}}{3x^2} $$

Comment: Thank you so much